# When redirecting the root domain of my site to the www subdomain every URL works except /robots.txt

Tags: heroku, dns, domain-forwarding

This issue only popped up a month ago when Moz reported it is no longer able to crawl our site, because the campaign is configured for our root domain, but all of our traffic gets forwarded to the 'www' subdomain.

So 'example.com/some-page.html' gets forwarded correctly to 'www.example.com/some-page.html' (as well as all other pages on our site).

'www.example.com/robots.txt' also works correctly.

'example.com/robots.txt' gets a connection timeout.

I've tested all of this thoroughly with https://httpstatus.io/

Our DNS registrar is GoDaddy, our site is hosted on Heroku, and our platform is Ruby on Rails.

Comment: how are you forwarding root to www? Are you using htaccess rules?

Comment: Through GoDaddy's forwarding option

Comment: I also forgot to mention that before being passed on to www.example.com, godaddy inserts two 302 Redirects, which always include the addition of five alpha characters and then removing them, ie it forwards from example.com/index.html to example.com/AZIFA/index.html and then back to example.com/index.html. From what I've ready they do this to prevent DDOS attacks, no clue if it would be pertinent to this issue